# angular-vs-repeat dynamic element height based on element DOM height

Tags: angular, virtualization

I have repeatable elements like boxes and every have different height with content inside it (tables etc) I need to update height of angular-vs-repeat virtualization viewport based on currently rendered box. How can I make it?

```
     <div vs-repeat="{'scrollParent': 'window'}" size="10" offset-before="1000" ng-style="{
        'height': 'calc(100%)',
        'overflow': 'auto',
        'overflow-anchor': 'none'
      }">
      <div class="ibox" ng-repeat="person in timeSheetListCtrl.groupedItems" ng-if="!timeSheetListCtrl.too_many_records">
          <h5>
            {{person.person_name}}
          </h5>
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <div class="timesheet-table table-responsive m-t">
            <table class="table th-small table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed m-b-none">
            <!-- table rendering here -->
 </table>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div ng-if="::timeSheetListCtrl.woTime[person.person_name]" class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
              </table>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="::timeSheetListCtrl.groupTotals[person.person_name]" class="col-md-12 col-lg-2">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
              </table>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="::timeSheetListCtrl.payrollSummary[person.person_name]" class="col-md-12 col-lg-2">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                          <!-- table rendering here -->
</table>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="::timeSheetListCtrl.extraSummary[person.person_name]" class="col-md-12 col-lg-2">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                          <!-- table rendering here -->
    </table>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="::timeSheetListCtrl.subTotalTime[person.person_name]" class="col-md-12 col-lg-2">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                <!-- table rendering here -->
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: `I have`. Then show it! :)

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko updated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items;">
  <div [style.height.px]="{{item.height}}"></div>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items;">
  <div [style.height]="'{{item.height}}px'"></div>
</div>
```